# Visual Studio Code "You don't have an extension for debugging 'Json with comments'. Shoud we find extension in store?"

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

When I'm trying to start launch.json (To start my extension for VScode), it gives error "You don't have an extension for debugging 'Json with comments'. Shoud we find extension in store?"... When I press find in marketplace, I can't find it:

[image: extension error message]